# How to declare database connection globaly in node.js

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I'm working with node.js and socket.io using mysql module in it. Is it possible to declare

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection(database);
```

as global? rather using it in all functions, so that i can use it in all functions even if each function has

```
connection.end();
```

in it??

Answer (score 0):

node.js has `GLOBAL` as the global to app. So you can do like this.

```
if (!GLOBAL.connection) {
    GLOBAL.connection = mysql.createConnection(database);
}
```

and when you like to end connection, use

```
if (GLOBAL.connection) 
    GLOBAL.connection.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid globals and use this initialize option, keeping global space clean:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18008471/491662